# android cant access application while async class is running

Tags: android, android-asynctask

**while i execute Async class** in my application at that particular time duration (while class process is run in background) **i can not access anything from my app**. i touch any where it does't work and after the Async class process is completed it runs normally.
   so, i want solution for that like if i want to make change in application then at that time  the updating process will run in background and i can also access this app. and make other request to application. so please anyone who have solution of my problem then please give me solution of this problem.

my code is given here

```
class GetUserDetail extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(wishlist.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "xyz"));
                        JSONObject json = jsonpd.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST",
                                params);
                        Log.d("Single user Details", json.toString());
                        // JSONObject mainJson = new
                        // JSONObject(json.toString());
                        JSONArray json_contents = json.getJSONArray("Success");

                        for (int i = 0; i < json_contents.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = json_contents.getJSONObject(i);
                        //  tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put(TAG_name, c.getString(TAG_name));
                            map.put(TAG_image, c.getString(TAG_image));
                            map.put(TAG_product_id, c.getString(TAG_product_id));
                            map.put(TAG_des, c.getString(TAG_des));
                            map.put(TAG_price, c.getString(TAG_price));

                            arraylist.add(map);

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapters = new WishListViewAdapter(wishlist.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            wishlist.setAdapter(adapters);

            // Close the progressdialog
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
```

now see this adapter class

```
public class WishListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String addtocartz="spiurl";
    TextView pname, pdes, pprice, pid;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    String PID, PNAME;
    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    JSONParser jsonpd = new JSONParser();
    UserSessionManager session;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public WishListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables

        ImageView pimage;
        Button addtocart;
        dec.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wishlist_row, parent, false);
        resultp = data.get(position);
        pname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.wpname);
        pdes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.wpdiscription);
        pprice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.wpprice);
        addtocart = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.wAdvance_Search_Button);
        pimage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.wpimage);

        if (resultp.get(Search.TAG_price) != ("null")) {
            pprice.setText("$"
                    + dec.format(Double.valueOf(resultp.get(wishlist.TAG_price))));

        } else {
            pprice.setText("$" + resultp.get(wishlist.TAG_price));

        }   
        pname.setText(resultp.get(wishlist.TAG_name));
        pdes.setText(resultp.get(wishlist.TAG_des));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(wishlist.TAG_image), pimage);
        addtocart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                session = new UserSessionManager(context);
                if (session.checkLogin())
                    finish();
                else{

                resultp = data.get(position);


                HashMap<String, String> users = session.getUserDetails();

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("customer_id", users
                        .get(UserSessionManager.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID)));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product_id", resultp
                        .get(wishlist.TAG_product_id)));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty", "1"));

                JSONObject json = jsonpd.makeHttpRequest(addtocartz, "POST",
                        params);

                pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Product successfully added to cart",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            private void finish() {
            }
        });

        return itemView;
    }

    public void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }
```

now what happening while i click on the button at that time app will stop like its hanging but actually at that time in background

```
HashMap<String, String> users = session.getUserDetails();

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("customer_id", users
                        .get(UserSessionManager.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID)));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product_id", resultp
                        .get(wishlist.TAG_product_id)));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty", "1"));

                JSONObject json = jsonpd.makeHttpRequest(addtocartz, "POST",
                        params);

                pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Product successfully added to cart",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

above code is running and while this process is execute after that i can again access this app normally.

hope now may clear about my issue.

Comment: can you please post you code?? what are you trying to do?

Comment: i touch any where it does't work and after the Async class process is completed it runs normally i can touch any where it work.

Comment: Are you sure you are using async task (different thread) for backgroung work? Seems like your main thread is busy with something that's why you can't interact with the app.

Comment: hmm.. then do u have solution to make it free from busy..?

Comment: As Ryderz said,remove runOnUiThread from doInBackground. Use UI thread  (main) only when you are making any changes to UI. Also you should not  initialize your adapter in postExecute as postExecute always runs on main thread. Initialize it out out Async Task and just change the values in adapter in postExecute.

Comment: yes prashant... i ll sure follow your instruction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `runOnUiThread` from `doInBackground`

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "xyz"));
                    JSONObject json = jsonpd.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST",
                            params);
                    Log.d("Single user Details", json.toString());
                    // JSONObject mainJson = new
                    // JSONObject(json.toString());
                    JSONArray json_contents = json.getJSONArray("Success");

                    for (int i = 0; i < json_contents.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = json_contents.getJSONObject(i);
                    //  tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(TAG_name, c.getString(TAG_name));
                        map.put(TAG_image, c.getString(TAG_image));
                        map.put(TAG_product_id, c.getString(TAG_product_id));
                        map.put(TAG_des, c.getString(TAG_des));
                        map.put(TAG_price, c.getString(TAG_price));

                        arraylist.add(map);

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          }       

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: So Ryderz my i use multiple Async class at same time or not?

Comment: yeah you can ... go through this :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29